# Why is there a DC component in the output spectrum from an op-amp adder?

Tags: amplitude-modulation, sinusoidal

I'm experimenting with a DSB-SC circuit using TINA simulation tool.
As input I'm using two sinusoids with frequencies of 500 and 1000 Hz, i.e. 0.05sin(2π500t) and 0.1sin(2π1000t) which are guided into an AD811 IC used as an adder. There are no offset voltages at any of the two sources.

I'm getting the Fourier analysis at the adder's output, and suprisingly, I'm getting a frequency component at 0 Hz along with expected 500 and 1000 Hz. Should I be getting a component at 0 Hz although no DC component is added?

[image]

Comment: What windowing function are you using, and what time period does the window cover?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know the wiring of your opamp.

Here is mine with "classical" operator ... Made with [microcap v12](https://archive.org/details/mc12cd_202110).

No 0 Hz frequency component, not same OP level.

[image]

Increasing "dynamic" scale ...

[image]

Comment: The spectrum is plotted over 3 decades of amplitude only (!). If the op-amp model has any offset, that offset will show up on the spectrum, it's just outside of the plot's boundary. MicroCap tries to be helpful and show only what would typically be considered "relevant", but to get the full picture the plot's vertical scale has to be manually forced to span say 8 decades at least.

Comment: Note that forcing to span 8 decades does not help (?) ... Although, transient are ok and shows a DC component if added.

Answer (score 0):

Run a DC operating point simulation and check whether your assumption of "there should be no DC" actually holds in practice. It doesn't take *much* DC offset to show up in the log-scaled power spectrum.

All real op-amps have some offset. The model used in TINA may have a typical DC offset just as a real chip would. If the DC measurement is anything but true zero, the power spectrum will show it.

Any non-zero DC value, no matter how small, will be visible on the simulated power spectrum. You're not doing a noise simulation. The spectrum is "clean" and has no noise floor, and it will gladly show *everything*, no matter how small - as there's no noise for it to get buried in.

The admonition to check your assumptions may well be summarized as *defensive engineering*, similar to *defensive driving*. Be especially alert when an assumption disagrees with the results. "There should be no DC" yet the results show DC. Perhaps there really **is** DC then. Easy to check, right?